# Pytest, vscode test explorer and integrated terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have trouble figuring out pytest in requards to pythonpath and the vscode test explorer.

My project structure looks like this:

```
analytics
├── worker
│   ├── src
|   ├── |── __init__.py
|   ├── |── data
|   ├── |── ├── __init__.py
|   ├── |── ├── connection.py
|   ├── |── main.py
|   ├── |── ...
│   ├── tests
|   ├── |── integration
|   ├── |── ├── ...
|   ├── |── unit
|   ├── |── ├── conftest.py
|   ├── |── ├── ...
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.dev
```

And my pyproject.toml looks like this:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
# ------------------------------- TOOL:PYTEST -------------------------------
pythonpath = ["./worker", "./worker/src"]
addopts = "-v"
python_files = "test_*.py"
```

In `conftest.py` I have the following import:

```py
from src.data.connection import Connection
```

In this scenario my integrated terminal lets me run `pytest` without errors. and I don't get any errors in `conftest.py`. But I get errors in the vscode test explorer.

If I move the `tests` folder to the root of the project, and change the import in `conftest.py` to:

```py
from worker.src.data.connection import Connection
```

I don't get error in the integrated terminal, and the test explorer. But I get import errors in `conftest.py`.

And if I prepend `worker.` to `from src.data.connection import Connection` I get errors in the integrated terminal, but not in the test explorer, or in `conftest.py`.

Can someone explain how i'm supposed to structure my project, and how I can get the test explorer to work?

Comment: Does this works if you add `"python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` to your settings.json?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Sadly it seems to have no effect.

Comment: But adding this `"python.testing.pytestArgs": ["worker/tests"]` makes it work 

Comment: Hi Lewi Uberg, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: As the `tests` directory is tucked away inside the `worker` directory, what would likely have worked in regards to the first comment is `"python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/worker"` (note the addition of `/worker` to the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some answers here, and some more research I made it work by adding `"python.testing.pytestArgs": ["worker/tests"]` to `settings.json`